# Strapi data losing

Tags: database, heroku, backend, strapi

I'm a new Strapi user. I uploaded my Strapi backend via Heroku, but the data I entered every night is lost and it's like my Strapi backend is a hard reset. I'm deploying a github repository manually in Heroku. Is there anyone who can help me with this?

I tried to redeploy but the next day I got the same error again.

Comment: How are you saving your data? Heroku dynos have an ephermal filesystem. Anything you write to the local disk will be lost frequently and unpredictably.

Comment: what kind of database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql